# Should I place a Al plate above or below power supply to heatsink to distribute heat better?

Tags: heatsink

I have a power supply mounted on an Al sheet (3mm thick) which is on top of a closet.  Considering only heat dissipation, should I place the fanless power supply above or below the Al sheet?

Comment: It depends on how the power supply is designed and which one gets you better thermal contact to the hot parts of the circuit.

Comment: Besides what Hearth said, the heat will eventually need to dissipate from the AL sheet to the air, so a diagram will help us understand the problem better.